# Jupyter Notebook cells won't run

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have opened a notebook using Anaconda, I entered the token and it opens fine. The kernel it is running is Python3. However, it is not running any cells.

I have tried checking the kernels installed, I have tried running jupyter troubleshoot in my command. My command keeps showing blocks like this:

```
    [I 17:36:41.918 NotebookApp] Adapting from protocol version 5.1 (kernel 543df2b4-283f-43bc-afee-c4580df2761b) to 5.3 (client).
[E 17:36:41.920 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/543df2b4-283f-43bc-afee-c4580df2761b/channels?session_id=aaa5c54bff4f44e2ac919aafb4973662 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/543df2b4-283f-43bc-afee-c4580df2761b/channels?session_id=aaa5c54bff4f44e2ac919aafb4973662', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Tamira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 546, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/Tamira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 274, in open
        self.create_stream()
      File "/Users/Tamira/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 127, in create_stream
        meth = getattr(km, 'connect_' + channel)
    AttributeError: 'MappingKernelManager' object has no attribute 'connect_control'
```

Comment: Did you check your python? Is it running outside the notebook?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1468793/attributeerror-mappingkernelmanager-object-has-no-attribute-connect-control

Answer (score 1):

The components for your Jupyter installation are out-of-date with respect to one another.

I suggest either reinstalling Anaconda from scratch or upgrading the individual packages used by the notebook.